# How do I use browser-specific API's in an isomorphic React App?

Tags: dom, reactjs, flux

I was reading several [style guides](https://github.com/Khan/style-guides/blob/master/style/react.md#pure-functions-of-props-and-state) on using react on the server side, and they all (rightfully) seem to suggest that components should be a pure function of `states` and `props`.

That begs a question that if I were to use a DOM API, say `window.innerWidth` or `canvas.getContext()`, which is the best place for doing so according to the `react + flux` philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` will only executed in client side, you can place browser-specific code there.

But if it's not enough, my recommendation it's use `DefinePlugin` if you prefer webpack as your build tool.(I believe there are plugins provide same feature if you prefer other build tool)

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __CLIENT__: true
})
```

And use conditional statement to judge whether the code is executed in browser environment.

Comment: okay... so none of the lifecycle methods are parsed on the server side (except render)?

Comment: componentWillMount is parsed in server side.
http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods